# Positive eigenvalues $\Rightarrow |A + A^T| >0$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A be real square matrix with positive eigenvalues. Then $|A + A^T| >0$.

I need help to prove or disprove the claim. From conditions I know that $|A|=|A^T|>0$, but how that translates into determinant of the sum?

Also, note, that A need not be symmetric.

Answer (score 3):

The statement is false.  Consider $$A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&2\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you, but it it possible to derive that positive eigenvalues may lead to, say, negative determinant of sum?

Comment: Yes, consider $A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 3 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: No, I mean, can we (without explicitly giving any matrix) show that positive eigenvalues may lead to nonpositive determinant of sum?

Comment: To show something *may* happen it suffices to provide one example, as Jimmy and I have done.